# Convert javascript variable “11:00 AM” to c# equivalent where SQL is in time format

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have following model properties

```
public class CallLog
{
      public int CallLogID { get; set; }
      public TimeSpan endTime { get; set; }
      public TimeSpan startTime { get; set; }
}
```

my api call is "/api/CallLog/AddCallLog". where CallLog data contain

```
startTime = "11:00 AM"
endTime = "11:30 AM"
```

And my api controller is

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddCallLog(CallLog callLog)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            success = false,
            errors = ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(k => ModelState[k].Errors)
                .Select(m => m.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
        });
    }

    CallLog.InsertCallLog(callLog);

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = callLog.CallLogID }, callLog);
}
```

It gives me the following error

> {"Error converting value \"11:00 AM\" to type 'System.TimeSpan'. Path 'startTime'....}
>   {"Error converting value \"11:30 AM\" to type 'System.TimeSpan'. Path 'endTime'....}

My question is what datatype i need for time like "11:00 AM". Remember my datatype in database for startTime and endTime is "time".

Comment: you can use timespan `TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(11,00,00);` will give you 11:00 AM

Answer (score 1):

From what the errors are saying, you may have to provide the correct conversion from `string` type `"11:30 AM"` to `TimeSpan` type. You could use `DateTime.ParseExact` with the convert pattern through parameter like this:

```
string pattern = "HH:mm 'AM'";
TimeSpan yourTimeSpan = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                      "11:30 AM",
                                      pattern,
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                      ).TimeOfDay;
```

It will give you timespan with value 11:30:00

So, you may modify your code to something like this:

```
private string _endTime;
public TimeSpan endTime 
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(
                                  _endTime,
                                  "HH:mm 'AM'",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                                  ).TimeOfDay;
    }            
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use a `DateTime` and ignore the **date** and to display just the time to the user, output it formatted to the user like this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("t"); // 11:00 AM
```

So you can change CallLog

```
public class CallLog
{
      public int CallLogID { get; set; }
      public DateTime endTime { get; set; }
      public DateTime startTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DateTime.Parse("11:00 AM").TimeOfDay
```

It gives you `TimeSpan` with value `11:00:00`.